# Getting video to load on basic web page, not working

Tags: javascript, html, video, web

I am trying to get a sample video to load on a webpage. I've never loaded a video from my computer onto a page before. According to w3 schools this should work however it is not working.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="videoPageCSS.css">
</head>


<body>
<div class id= videoContainer>
<embed src="test.mp4" width="200" height="200">
</div>
<div class id= description>
<p>A sample video that will not go to full screen on IOS phone</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: what browser are you using. certain browsers only support certain video formats. eg, if you're using safari, it will not work in this case as safari doesn't support mp4.

Comment: also for formatting, you should wrap id values in quotes. for example, `id="videoContainer"`

Comment: Have you tested using the video tag instead of embed?

Comment: @adanot lol i didn't even catch that. regardless, the above code worked when testing locally for me

Comment: Why is it not working for me? This is odd. I'm using chrome, I tried explorer still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed src="test.mp4" width="200" height="200">
```

the above code is wrong.

try this down below

```
<video autoplay height="400" width="300">
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="test.ogg" type="video/ogg"> <!-- even though you don't have ogg video file,    
I reccomend you make a copy of your mp4 and convert it to ogg so that you video ca run on   
all major browsers and be cross-browser compatible. -->
</video>
```

also you don't need to create whitespaces between exclamation point and DOCTYPE in html5 doctype declaration (